# Make shell does not inherit console shell environment variables

Tags: ruby, shell, makefile, rvm

I am working on a Makefile to build an application where frontend and backend are completely separated in two different directories, like:

```
- myapp
  |_be
  |_fe
```

This is my Makefile:

```
.ONESHELL:

all: frontend backend

frontend:
    cd ./fe && \
    npm install && \
    ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js

backend: clean
    cd ./be && \
    gem install bundler && \
    bundle install

clean:
    rm -f ./fe/public/bundle.js && rm -rf ./fe/public/resources 

webpack:
    cd ./fe && \
    .node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js

test:
    cd ./fe && \
    npm test

run:
    cd ./be && \
    rackup config.ru
```

The frontend is a React application and it is being built correctly when I type `make frontend`. No issues here.

But the backend is a Rack application written in Ruby. During the build process I need to enter its directory (`be`), make sure bundler is installed and run `bundle install`.

It happens that `make` creates its own shell to run the Makefile commands. And this shell does NOT inherit the environment variables of the console shell I am working. This turns out to be a problem to me, because I use `rvm` and `rvm` uses some environment variables to pick the correct gems. I use the `.ruby-gemset` and `.ruby-version` to create a private bundle to my application, not using the default gemset. This is necessary, because I have applications using many different Ruby versions and don't want to care about this.

This particular application uses JRuby 9.1.7.0 and then my `Gemfile` (inside `be` directory) has the following line:

```
ruby '2.3.1', :engine => 'jruby', :engine_version => '9.1.7.0'
```

I noticed all this issue because I got the following error when I typed `make backend`:

> Your Ruby engine is ruby, but your Gemfile specified jruby

As far as I know `rvm` (and I know it quite well), this means it is trying to use my default Ruby version (which is set to Ruby 2.5.0) as engine, instead of the correct JRuby version.

Now, here is my question: **Is there a way to force the make inner shell to use the same configuration of the console shell I am using?**

This would solve the issue, because the console shell is already configured by `rvm`. I know it is because when I enter the `be` directory manually and run `bundle install` inside it, everything goes fine.

I used the `.ONESHELL` directive to force `make` to do this, but it seems it is not what I need.

Suggestions?

**EDIT:** `make` [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Environment.html#Environment) says the `-e` flag may be used to force the `make` grab all console shell variables. I tried it and it didn't work.

**EDIT:** It all works if I do

```
rvm use --default jruby-9.1.7.0
```

before doing my `make backend`. But for many reasons it is not convenient to do this. Besides, I really believe this is a better way to do this. `make` is too smart not to allow something as simple as this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are 2 problems:

1) when `rvm` creates its environment variables, it does not `export` them, so they are not visible to child shells, and

2) because the child shell is not started as a login shell, it does not see and process the `rvm` function declarations, and can therefore not execute `rvm my-ruby-version`.

Here are a couple of workarounds:

Before creating the child shell, do something like this:

```
export RVM_VERSION=`rvm current`
```

When starting the child shell, do so in login mode:

```
zsh --login
```

or

```
bash --login
```

Then, rvm should be a function, and this should work:

```
rvm $RVM_VERSION
```

Answer (score 0):

First I added two lines to my `backend:` recipe, which now was reading

```
backend:
    cd ./be && \
    source $(HOME)/.rvm/scripts/rvm && \
    rvm use jruby-9.1.7.0 && \
    gem install bundler && \
    bundle install
```

The idea was setting the correct Ruby (JRuby 9.1.7.0) without having to change it permanently at the console.

It happened this wouldn't work, because I wasn't choosing the shell I was using and it seems for some reason it wasn't `/bin/bash` and `source` wouldn't work. As a sequel, `rvm` wouldn't work either and I would receive that irritating message saying

> rvm is not a function

Then I added

```
SHELL = /bin/bash
```

right after the `.ONESHELL:` directive.

And now everything worked fine!